# CV - qualifiers of an auto variable

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I found [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_03.html) the following "rule":

> [...] auto drops const and volatile qualifiers only if they're at the top or **right below an outermost reference** [...]

I understand that top-level cv-qualifiers are a description of the variable itself (compared to the description of what it is pointing to or referencing). But when is a cv-qualifier "right below an outermost reference" and why would auto drop it (probably the first question answers the second one as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*cv* right below an outermost reference" means that the reference is to a *cv*-qualified type. For example, take this function:

```
const int& foo();
```

The type "right below the outermost reference" is `const int`, which means the `const` is there as well. In this code:

```
auto i = foo();
```

the type of `i` is `int`, not `const int` or `const int&`.

Examples of a `const`which is *not* right below an outermost reference are:

```
const char* bar();
const double* volatile & baz();
```

Using `auto` to take calls of these functions would deduce to type `const char*` and `const double*`, respectively.

Comment: This code does not compile, and I think it shouldn't. const int x = 10;
const int & a = x;
auto &b = a;
b = 500; The const qualifier should not be dropped.

Comment: @user42768 But you're not using `auto`, you're using `auto&` in your example. An entirely different kettle of fish.

Comment: I thought adding adornments to the auto keyword would still find the type as usual, and then add the adornments to it (maybe considering reference collapsing). So there are other rules when using auto & and auto &&?

Comment: I apologize, the description of this exception was on the same page that I referenced (at **First Amendment**).