# Why can I mutate member variable in a const object which is the result of a returning const object function?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto

```cpp
struct Dummy {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 6;

    const Dummy share() {
        return Dummy{};
    }
};
```

There is a member function called `share()` which returns a const `Dummy` object in the `Dummy` structure above. I except that I can't mutate the object returning from the `share()` function.
However, **the result showed that the object is mutable**. I paste experimental code below for more details.

```cpp
int main() {
    Dummy d1;
    auto d2 = d1.share();
    d2.a = 10;
    // the output is 10.
    std::cout << "d2.a is " << d2.a << std::endl; 
}
```

So why can I mutate member variable in this const object?

Comment: Because `d2` is not const?

Comment: and you make a copy^_^

Comment: @daoliker The const qualifier is discarded when the type placeholder auto is deduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "auto" resolves to "Dummy", not "const Dummy". Thus, d2 is (formally) copy-constructed from the result of share, and it can be modified. You can force d2 to be immutable (independent of the return type of share) by saying "const auto".

In particular, the inference performed by "auto" drops the *outermost* layer of const/volatile qualifiers if they exist, as explained in this other question: [CV - qualifiers of an auto variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492967/cv-qualifiers-of-an-auto-variable)

Comment: Is it possible to let `auto` resolve `const Dummy`?

Comment: No, because auto means "give me a normal variable that can take the result of this expression". To exactly replicate the type of the function result, I think you can use "decltype(auto)" instead.

Comment: @JavierMartín Be careful that true pure rvalues are never const qualified, only classes can be.

Comment: @curiousguy in the sense that "const int&&" is meaningless because "const int&" also captures such a value?

Answer (score 3):

```
auto d2 = d1.share();
```

Here you are copying the `const` object that `d1.share()` returns into a new non-const variable `d2`, and then you modify the values of `d2`, not the values of the `const` object returned by `d1.share()`!

What you are asking about is this:

```
d1.share().a = 5;
```

This will give you an error that you can't change a value of a `const` variable.